# Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am experiencing a problem with jQuery, I am putting this code into TypeScript and it is simply giving error:

```
import $ = require("jquery");

$('element').sort(function(a,b){
   // code<> 
})
```

This is the image in more detail:

[image]

I'm using jQuery 3.4.1 on Electron, why are you giving this error?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you think that there's a `.sort()` method? Even jQuery itself can't find one -> https://api.jquery.com/sort/ ;)

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4349 -> _"Also note that sort is not part of the documented interface of jQuery collections. We make no guarantees about its behavior or even its presence. Please rewrite expressions like `$(selector).sort(fn)` to e.g. `$( $(selector).toArray().sort(fn) )`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort is a method on an array, jQuery elements are not put into an array but instead a jQuery object ( I believe )
`$('element').toArray().sort(...)` would work